# Perguntas criadas para troca de votos

Tags: debate, reputação

Pode ser uma percepção errada, mas a alguns dias, eu reparei em algumas perguntas, que claramente seriam fechadas, feitas por pessoas com alguma reputação, e todas com 2 votos, a principio não estranhei, já que é super comum perguntas ruins receberem votos, mas depois de ler a discussão sobre o ganho de reputação por voto aqui no meta, isso me deixou intrigado..

Existe a possibilidade de pessoas estarem combinando ou criando contas falsas para aumentar reputação? Se sim, existe alguma forma de verificar e denunciar isso?